# Set Bounds for Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a game that I need to have bounds for the character, such as he can't walk into the trees, etc.  How would I add a bounds so that the character can not walk into these boundaries.  By the way, I use the direction keys to move it if it helps.

If you need my javascript, just let me know.

Comment: You might like using a game library like CAAT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the principles from [this article](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-check-boundaries-in-your-html5-game.html) I'd suggest to first detect a collision on a set of actors (in this instance your trees) and if a collision occurs after executing the movement, place the player character back to where he was just before. This is the simplest way. You could also simulate the coords that your character would have after the movement, and see if that would collide with your trees, if not do the movement else, do nothing.